# Obtaining previous adt list

Tags: c, list, data-structures, struct

```
  Int test(List *L, int c, List *PrevL){

addItem(L,c);

return (L, C, PrevL);
}
```

How can I obtain the Previous list everytime the method returns?
I've tried this but it didnt work

```
 Int test(List *L, int c, List *PrevL, int C){

addItem(L,c);
if (c > 0)
addItem (L, L->item[C -1)
return (L, C, PrevL, c + 1);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you grab a basic tutorial/book and learn the fundamentals of C first. Your code isn't valid C syntax. In particular in C a function can only return one value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Also study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Your code doesn't compile, and has at least 2 types that you've not shown the definition for.   You seem to be using the comma operator rather extensively, and pointlessly (but probably because you're misunderstanding something).

Answer (score 0):

this was a nice try:

```
  Int test(List *L, int c, List *PrevL){

addItem(L,c);

return (L, C, PrevL);
}
```

However, 'Int' is not a valid type for a function return, or anything else.

The following would be much closer to what your asking for:

```
List *test(List *L, int c, List *PrevL)
{
    addItem(L,c);
    return (PrevL);
}
```

and notice how much easier it is to read when the braces are vertically aligned and the code block is consistently indented.

This does make the assumption that the parameter 'PrevL'  is a pointer to the previous list.

Notice that the return type 'List *' matches the type of the thing to be returned.

Note: the C language is case sensitive, so 'Int' is not the same as 'int'